# Drawing a variable length line in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, shapes

I'm doing an Augmented Reality app in which the main screen contains several *ARViews* shown over the camera preview. These ARViews are extended LinearLayout with TextViews inside.
These views are drawn at different vertical positions on the screen. Now I'd like to draw a vertical line from the middle of each view to the middle of the height of the screen, as shown on the screenshot below.

[image]

Of course the views move when the user moves the device, so that the length of the line changes.

How can add this to my ARView?

```
public class ARView extends LinearLayout
{    
    public float azimuth = 0;        
    public float inclination = 0;
    public Location location;
    public int position;

    TextView title, type, distance;

    public int X, Y;

    public ARView(final Context context, int ind)
    {        
        super(context);  
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ar_item, this ,true);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.ar_item, null);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);
        distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
    }
}
```

**ar_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ar_item" android:layout_width="202dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp" android:background="@drawable/bg_item_ar"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp" android:clickable="true">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp" android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/type" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp" android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#C6C6C6" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuld create a ViewGroup where all those views are included which should cover the whole width and height. Now you could add into the view group another view that should act as a background with your custom drawing. You could also create a new relative layout and to all extra stuff in there.